# How do I print special characters in JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, json, special-characters

```
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = array(
                    'id' => $row['id'],
                    'shipDataLastLocaltion' => $row['SDLLP']
                   );
}

print '{"data": ';
echo json_encode($rows, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
print "}";
$this->response('', 200);
```

**Data in the table:**

```
 $row['SDLLP'] //-> "Istanbul’Beşiktaş&quot;point:3&quot;"
```

**Error screen:**

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 10 of the JSON data

**The reason for the error:**

These characters are in the table `&quot;` and `’`

JSON does not work because of these characters - I used this function for this, but it did not work.

I tried this for the solution `htmlspecialchars` and other methods I found on the internet but all method did not work.

What could be the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

While printing just use backslash \ before each and every special character. It will start accepting those characters as json simple string for example:

```
\" quotation
\\ backslash
```

Pick the data using your server side language and add backslash \ before each and every special character and then make the json and return it to the client side.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These unwanted characters coming from Database i think. First of all you need to set collation [Mysql collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-database.html)

If still you have a problem you have to use iconv function to change encoding of these words.

Answer (score 0):

Is just enough

```
// Change character set to utf8
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
```

or

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```